# "Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)" while renewing Certbot

Tags: linux, apache, centos7, portforwarding, certbot

I am facing the following error when I try to renew my ssl certificate using

```
certbot renew
```

> Challenge failed for domain ***********.com

> Some challenges have failed.

> The following errors were reported by the server:

> Domain: arjunbroker.com
> Type:   connection
> Detail: Fetching
> http://arjunbroker.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/F9nlyrRQBpJGOpPLHGPCj1vzdJOd_rBISU7q2aX7t_o:
> Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)

I have checked UFW and firewalld. And both port 80 and 443 are open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally realised that prior to installing SSL on this server, I used to forward port 80 to port 8080 using

```
 sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

So I simply forwarded port 80 back to port 80.

Lesson learnt, for Certbot to work port 80 forwarding should be in place.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed that in AWS EC2 updating the Group Security like this:
[image]

More about EC2 Group Security: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html

Comment: for me it was adding 0.0.0.0/0 to port 80, even though the other wildcard format for 80 was already set and had been working for years

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was that Let's Encrypt uses IPv6 if possible to do the http challenge and my site worked fine over IPv4 but not over IPv6 (as I had it setup wrong). You can use [this site](https://www.ipv6-test.com/validate.php) to test your IPv6 setup.

Answer (score 0):

I finally realized that I ONLY had http/https open to my test client machines. I opened them wide for the certbot run then closed them again. I'll try to determine what IP needs to be open for letsencrypt probes so I can automate the certbot renewals.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29913832)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by disabling **'Permanent SEO-safe 301 redirect from HTTP to HTTPS'** (in Hosting Settings for Plesk / CentOS Linux 7.9).

LetsEncrypt wouldn't assign or renew its SSL certificates otherwise. Spent a day re-configuring, DNS, panel.ini, firewall, etc., and eventually **pinpointed** this as the specific cause.

The issue surfaced about 10 months ago and we only realised what was happening recently.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the behaviour when your routers IP address changes. For me it appeared like everything was in order and eventually I found out my house had its IP changed - so simply reallocating it with my domain name provider fixed the issue.

To avoid this in the future, you can look into configuring your router with a static IP through your ISP.